# Apply dollar currency sign to money value in datagrid view

Tags: vb6

I am trying to change the currency symbol on a datagrid view, this works fine for local currency(euro):

```
DBTotalGrid.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C"
 but I can't change to a dollar sign, the following has no effect:
 DBTotalGrid.Columns(8).DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("c", "us")
```

I can't format to a string as computations are performed on the value of the cell.

Comment: Rather than converting to a string, which will cause the mentioned problem, can you not display it as a number and just prefix with a dollar sign using concatenation?

Comment: That looks like .NET code not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get print the character in Binary Format to send it to the Grid.

Just write the Character $ => Chr(36) =>  It would print $

Your Problem would be resolved.